# Extract list from html with xpath, with linebreaks

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath

How can I extract `['First one', 'Second two', 'Third']` from this with xpath?

```
s = """
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
<tbody><tr> 
<th class="searchResults" style="width:75px">First<br>one</th> 
<th class="searchResults" style="width:150px">Second<br>two</th> 
<th class="searchResults" style="width:95px">Third<br></th> 
</tr> 
</tbody></table>
"""
import lxml.html as LH
e = LH.fromstring(s)
e.xpath('/th[@class="searchResults"]/text()')
```

splits on the `<br>` too, which I don't want. I've tried `string()` and `normalize-space()`, but can't get it quite right.

Comment: Is there an issue with doing `s=s.replace('<br>', ' ')` beforehand?

Comment: Does it have to be a xpath-only solution? `[' '.join(node.itertext()) for node in e.xpath('//th[@class="searchResults"]')]` would do it.

Comment: Try `e.xpath('normalize-space()').split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, there is no pure XPath solution in your actual situation since `lxml` only supports XPath 1.0. But using XPath 2.0 and above you can use `string-join()` function and you can call function in path step (see the demo [here](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable+all+extensions&data=%3Ctable+cellpadding%3D%220%22+cellspacing%3D%220%22+border%3D%220%22%3E+%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%3Ctr%3E+%0D%0A%3Cth+class%3D%22searchResults%22+style%3D%22width%3A75px%22%3EFirst%3Cbr%2F%3Eone%3C%2Fth%3E+%0D%0A%3Cth+class%3D%22searchResults%22+style%3D%22width%3A150px%22%3ESecond%3Cbr%2F%3Etwo%3C%2Fth%3E+%0D%0A%3Cth+class%3D%22searchResults%22+style%3D%22width%3A95px%22%3EThird%3Cbr%2F%3E%3C%2Fth%3E+%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E+%0D%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%3C%2Ftable%3E&extract=%2F%2Fth[%40class%3D%27searchResults%27]%2Fstring-join(text()%2C+%27+%27)&extract-kind=xpath3&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)):

```
//th[@class='searchResults']/string-join(text(), ' ')
```

The XPath works about the same way as the snippet mentioned by [@Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) in the comment :

```
[' '.join(node.itertext()) for node in e.xpath('//th[@class="searchResults"]')]
```